# Where can I find my redis server logs Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I cannot seem to find my redis logs

I have looked in the default location like /var/logs/ [/redis], also does not seem like my redis is installed in the /etc/redis/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are in luck, I just solved your problem.

The easiest way to find your redis installation is to search your entire HDD for the redis folder with 'find'

`sudo find / -name redis -type d`

The result on my box was

`/opt/bitnami/redis`

The server logs were located in

`/opt/bitnami/redis/var/log/`